# Vertical offset on a UICollectionView column

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, interface-builder

Image on right is what I try to achieve

[image]
Does anyone know how I could achieve this on a two column UICollectionView ?
I'm able to discern my columns by testing if (indexPath.row % 2 = 0) but I can't manage to achieve this result.

Is their a simple way to do so ? Or would I need a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout ?

Note : All my cells are the same size.

Comment: I think you should custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Or you can take a look at this https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` and that's simple to achieve. All you need is the following:

1. [prepare()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617752-prepare): Perform the up-front calculations needed to provide layout information
2. [collectionViewContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize): Return the overall size of the entire content area based on your initial calculations
3. [layoutAttributesForElements(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617769-layoutattributesforelements): Return the attributes for cells and views that are in the specified rectangle

Now that we have cells of the same size it's pretty easy to achieve.

Let's declare few variables to use:

```
    // Adjust this as you need
    fileprivate var offset: CGFloat = 50

    //    Properties for configuring the layout: the number of columns and the cell padding.
    fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 2
    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 10

    //    Cache the calculated attributes. When you call prepare(), you’ll calculate the attributes for all items and add them to the cache. You can be efficient and 
    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    //    Properties to store the content size.
    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }
```

Next let's override the `prepare()` method

```
    override func prepare() {
        // If cache is empty and the collection view exists – calculate the layout attributes
        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        // xOffset: array with the x-coordinate for every column based on the column widths
        // yOffset: array with the y-position for every column, Using odd-even logic to push the even cell upwards and odd cells down.
        let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0

        var yOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for i in 0..<numberOfColumns {
            yOffset.append((i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : offset)
        }

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            // Calculate insetFrame that can be set to the attribute
            let cellHeight = columnWidth - (cellPadding * 2)
            let height = cellPadding * 2 + cellHeight
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

            // Create an instance of UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute, sets its frame using insetFrame and appends the attributes to cache.
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            // Update the contentHeight to account for the frame of the newly calculated item. It then advances the yOffset for the current column based on the frame
            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

            column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
        }
    }
```

Last we need `collectionViewContentSize` and `layoutAttributesForElements(in:)`

```
    //    Using contentWidth and contentHeight from previous steps, calculate collectionViewContentSize.
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }
```

You can find [gist](https://gist.github.com/VivekMolkar/d190d702f33361f11307eadfa2699a3f) with the class.

This is how it appears:

[image: Demo]

Note: It is just a demo, you may have to tweak it according to your needs.

Hope It Helps!

Comment: Impressive ! It really helped thank you !!!
Can I ask you how to reduce the spacing between the two columns and between the lines ?

Comment: You can expose the `cellPadding` to adjust padding. I believe using protocols and delegates is usually the best approach.