# How do I achieve this layout, I just need to apply Y offset for even row numbers?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, scroll, collectionview

I have referred to this question

[image]

[Refer to this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488825/vertical-offset-on-a-uicollectionview-column)

and the solution provided, when I implement it, I am observing a strange behaviour. Whenever a user add new item to collection view cell. It appears but other collection view cell which was already there in collection view disappears.

Only after restarting the app and view did load method is called. I am able to see all the collection view items. It even crash if I try to add two items without restarting the app.

It crashes at out of range error in collection view flow layout.

This is the collectionviewflowlayout mentioned in that answer

```
`import UIKit

class HiveLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    // Adjust this as you need
    fileprivate var offset: CGFloat = 30
    

    //    Properties for configuring the layout: the number of columns and the cell padding.
    fileprivate var numberOfColumns = 2
    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 10

    //    Cache the calculated attributes. When you call prepare(), you’ll calculate the attributes for all items and add them to the cache. You can be efficient and query the cache instead of recalculating them every time.
    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    //    Properties to store the content size.
    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    //    Using contentWidth and contentHeight from previous steps, calculate collectionViewContentSize.
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func prepare() {
        // If cache is empty and the collection view exists – calculate the layout attributes
        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        // xOffset: array with the x-coordinate for every column based on the column widths
        // yOffset: array with the y-position for every column, Using odd-even logic to push the even cell upwards and odd cells down.
        let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0

        var yOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for i in 0..<numberOfColumns {
            yOffset.append((i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : offset)
        }

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            
            let columnWidths = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
            

            // Calculate insetFrame that can be set to the attribute
//            let cellHeight = columnWidth - (cellPadding * 2)
//            let height = 250.0
            let height = columnWidths * 1.5
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: CGFloat(height))
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

            // Create an instance of UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute, sets its frame using insetFrame and appends the attributes to cache.
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            // Update the contentHeight to account for the frame of the newly calculated item. It then advances the yOffset for the current column based on the frame
            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + CGFloat(height)

            column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
        }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Whenever a user add new item to collection view cell. It appears but other collection view cell which was already there in collection view disappears."* -- First, that's confusing... is the user adding another CELL? Or is the user doing something that adds something (a subview?) to an EXISTING cell? You've shown only the code for your layout -- you haven't shown any code that relates to "adding" anything.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your problem is:

- If you add new data and reload the collection view then it does not show the new data in the view
- If you insert new data into the list data and reload the collection view then it will be showing new data and at the same time some old data will be gone also
- The collection view can only show when you restart the app as you say

I have tried that problem and fix it like this, you just need to remove the condition to check the cache is empty and then the collection view can reload new data.

```
import UIKit
class HiveLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    
    ....
    
    override func prepare() {
        // If cache is empty and the collection view exists – calculate the layout attributes
        // Here I remove this codition: cache.isEmpty == true
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

    ....

    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: Man, You are a life saver :) I have been breaking head for days with this. And feel so dumb to know it just need a little fix :) 

Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` to achieve this layout. Once you get the idea it's much simpler than `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (at least in my opinion).
Please note that I haved used `UICollectionViewDataSource` to keep it simple. You can of course use `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` instead.

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var items: [UIColor] = (1...16).map { _ in .systemTeal }
    
    private let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: .createCompositionalLayout())
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCollectionView()
    }
    
    private func setupCollectionView() {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCell.reuseID)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 8
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding)
        ])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? MyCell
        
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell?.set(bgColor: item, text: "\(indexPath.row)")
        
        return cell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

**`UICollectionViewLayout` Extension:**

```
extension UICollectionViewLayout {
    static func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout{
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            //Item
            let elementSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.3)
            )
            
            let leftItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: elementSize)
            
            let rightItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: elementSize)
            rightItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 40, leading: 0, bottom: -40, trailing: 0)
            
            //Vertical Groups
            let verticalGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.48),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)
            )
            
            let leftVerticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: verticalGroupSize, subitem: leftItem, count: 1)
            leftVerticalGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)

            let rightVerticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: verticalGroupSize, subitem: rightItem, count: 1)
            rightVerticalGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)
            
            //Horizontal Group
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1/4)
            )
            
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [leftVerticalGroup, rightVerticalGroup])
            group.interItemSpacing = .flexible(5)
            
            //Section
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.interGroupSpacing = 10
            return section
        }
    }
}
```

**Collection View Cell:**

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static var reuseID: String { String(describing: self) }
    
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        setupLabel()
    }
    
    private func setupLabel() {
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func set(bgColor: UIColor, text: String) {
        contentView.backgroundColor = bgColor
        label.text = text
    }
}
```

You should be able to see the following result by simply adding the provided code to your project (in a new empty Storyboard application just remove the default `ViewController`)

[image: Expected Result]

Now there shouldn't be any problems if you add some items to `items` and call `collectionView.reloadData()`.
See this link to get started with `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`: https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/new-collection-view-apis-composite-layout/

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. I am new to App development. and you have just made it way better to learn. Definitely gonna learn it and apply. 

Thanks again for helping out :) Means a lot

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer was useful to you, please consider upvoting :-)...

Comment: Have upvoted already, but since im new and having low reputation, it said its recorded but wont show. :-/